# Does javascript loaded via .load run even after it's "deleted"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know any better way of asking this, or search for it, so here it goes:

I have a webpage that's basically a menu and a big white DIV in the center. All the subpages are loaded inside that div via .load. This is all fine, but:
[image]

I want to know if scripts loaded with the page are still going to run after the div's content is changed to another sub-page. To get what I mean, please visit http://carnbox.zapto.org (testing VPS) and log in using the credentials tomi : tomi .
Once logged in, go ahead and click on "My Services". All these scripts are inlined in the PHP pages that display the content. I found their lenght to be too small to make them external, and I wished to only load the scripts when viewing the page so the initial loading time of the website is smaller.
[image]

After clicking on another page, which will replace the contents of the white space with another page, will the setintervals from the previous page still be running? Will the scripts still be loaded in the user's browser or will they also be wiped?

Or more importantly, will swithing between the pages multiple times cause any trouble for the users?

Is this error related to the way I'm loading scripts, and should I switch to external files and jquery.getscript() ?

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of 
its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, 
check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/
```

Comment: *"To get what I mean, please visit ... (testing VPS) and log in using the credentials tomi : tomi ."* That's not how SO works. The content of the question must be **in the question**, not just linked. Links rot, and people shouldn't have to visit some random site to help you. Remember, your question isn't just to help you now, but to help others in the future. As soon as external content changes, a question relying on it becomes meaningless.

Comment: Okay, I will edit the question to explain everything(tho it already pretty much does) and leave the link just for the curious

Comment: Agreed, it pretty much does. You could remove the bit about the external site and probably condense a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, JavaScript code loaded by `.load` continues running even if the elements it was loaded with are removed from the DOM. Removing a `script` tag has no effect whatsoever on the code that the `script` loaded.

Here's a live example doing the same thing with `html` (`load` ends up calling `html` under the covers):

```js
var content = [
  // foo
  "This loads a script saying 'foo' once a second " +
  "for 100 seconds." +
  "<script>" +
  "var fooCounter = 0;\n" +
  "var fooTimer = setInterval(function() {\n" +
  "    $('<p>Foo</p>').appendTo(document.body);\n" +
  "    if (++fooCounter >= 100) {\n" +
  "        clearInterval(fooTimer);\n" +
  "    }\n" +
  "}, 1000);\n" +
  "</scr" + "ipt>",
  // bar
  "This loads a script saying 'bar' once a second " +
  "for 100 seconds." +
  "<script>" +
  "var barCounter = 0;\n" +
  "var barTimer = setInterval(function() {\n" +
  "    $('<p>Bar</p>').appendTo(document.body);\n" +
  "    if (++barCounter >= 100) {\n" +
  "        clearInterval(barTimer);\n" +
  "    }\n" +
  "}, 1000);\n" +
  "</scr" + "ipt>"
  ];
$(".load").on("click", function() {
  $("#target").html(content[this.getAttribute("data-index")]);
});
```

```html
<p>Click 'Load Foo', which loads content in to a target div, then once you see its script running, click 'Load Bar', which replaces the content in that div with new content. Note that now both scripts are running.</p>
<input type="button" data-index="0" class="load" value="Load Foo">
<input type="button" data-index="1" class="load" value="Load Bar">
<div id="target"></div>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Alright. So if the page is loaded twice in a row, will the scripts overlap, or will only the first one run? I don't see any errors being thrown (like conflicting vars or functions). What would be a good way to stop the scripts from running once the user left the page?

Comment: @aron9forever: Both scripts continue to run. JavaScript doesn't care about duplicate function declarations or `var` statements. Eventually I'd expect something would stomp on something. Your best bet is probably to use an `iframe` rather than `div` and remove and recreate it when changing, so each thing you load gets a new, fresh window to run and the old window is discarded.

Comment: Even I would like to know how memory clean up is done, I know it happens in all the MVC frameworks but not sure how its done under the hood.

Comment: I've used iframes in the past and they were a nightmare to handle. They'd also mess up indexing in search engines. One solution I could think of (which is used in the past for other stuff) is creating a global var called page, which will hold a number for each different page. Then just enclose any running script inside a if(page===thispagenumber) {} . The var's value would be updated every time a user clicks a menu button to navigate to a different page.

Comment: @aron9forever: Do you control the pages you're loading? I didn't realize that. If you do, just have them have a function they define that disconnects all event handlers and stops all timed callbacks, and have them only create properties on a single object which is referenced from a well-known name (like `page`). Then when switching pages, if you have a `page`, you do: `page.cleanup(); page = null;` to release the old page's resources before loading the new one. If you *don't* control the contents of the pages, `iframe`s are your only reliable option.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder could you please explain what you mean by control the pages?

Comment: @aron9forever: If you control their content. E.g., what they have in them that creates JavaScript functions and globals and such.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh yes, of course, I only load local pages containing blank html and js, since they inherit everything from the index. So if this is the case, I can indeed clear everything once the page is left. Thanks for clearing this up